# auto refresh doesn't retain the sort value in java script

Tags: javascript, sorting

My javascript onload function passing 2 functions

when I click on sort column in table it is in sorted state as long as the refresh page is not loaded . Once the refresh is called though onload function the page didn't retain the sorting column.

Any help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: may be you can use the browser's localStorage

Comment: A variable in javascript goes away after refresh unless you pass it through a form, keep it in a cookie, localstorage, or persist it through a server means

Answer (score 0):

localStorage or sessionStorage would be helpful, depending upon your need.

Try

**To Store item:**

```
localStorage.setItem('sort', sortedArrayInstance);
```

**To Receive back the item**

```
var tempSortArray = localStorage.getItem('sort');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to know if we can store the sorted table data using localstorage

Comment: Yup you can store any data. Basically browser stores values as key-value pair. So the key should be String and Value could be any object type supported by Javascript.